# How can I import a file (.txt) in R?

Tags: r

I´m trying to make a code that detects if there is a .txt file called "mycode.txt" imported, if it is already imported convert it in a dataframe and use it, if not, create a new dataframe and save it as "mycode.txt". I have used different ways, but I can´t achieve it, here is how I try it:

```
if(file.exists==TRUE){
  file.exists("mycode.txt")
  table <- read.table("mycode.txt")
  gamers <- table[,1]
  games <- table[,2]
  scores <- table[,3]
  table <- data.frame(gamers,games,scores)
}
else{
  gamers <- c()
  games <- c()
  scores <- c()
  table <- data.frame(gamers,games,scores)
}
```

```
      table <- rbind(table,name1)
      write.table(table,file="mycode.txt")
```

I have a .txt file in my desktop with this info:

```
"gamers" "games" "scores"
"1" "Rebeca" "3" "200"
"2" "Lucas" "1" "100"
"3" "Mario" "3" "205"
```

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution. The problem is the way you use `file.exists()`.

```
if (file.exists("pathtoyourfile/test.txt") == TRUE) {
  df1 = read.table("pathtoyourfile/test.txt")
} else {
  df = mtcars # mtcars is a base R dataset
  write.table(df, file = "test.txt")
}
```

Of course this can be enhanced to avoid harcoding the path (good practice) but this is not the question.

Comment: I did as you told me, and it works partially. The problem I think is that I import the .txt file wrong. I insert the .txt like this: "Import Dataset", "From text", and I choose the .txt. The problem is when I write file.exists("mycode.txt"), the program tell "FALSE". So I think I import the .txt in a wrong form, do you know how to import properly?

Comment: Have you checked the path to you file and typos ? like `/` or ` \ ` ? The function `file.exists()` just check if the file is on your hard drive, it does not import it. The function `read.table()` is the one importing the file. With the suggested code you do not need to use RStudio "manual" import file buttons. I am not sure to understand properly, does this comment help?

Comment: @JiakaiDong have you find a way to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying the code below?

```
if (file.exists("mycode.txt")) {
  table <- read.table(file = "mycode.txt", header = TRUE)
} else {
  table <- data.frame()
}
```

Comment: I did as you told me, and it works partially. The problem I think is that I import the .txt file wrong. I insert the .txt like this: "Import Dataset", "From text", and I choose the .txt. The problem is when I write file.exists("mycode.txt"), the program tell "FALSE". So I think I import the .txt in a wrong form, do you know how to import properly?

Comment: @JiakaiDong sorry that I have no clue what happened when you import your file